# Can a MongoDB user with read role delete collections and databases?

Tags: mongodb

I want to create a user that only has permission to view the information contained in a database called 'apigtac'. When I pull up the container where I have MongoDB, the following initialization script is executed:

```
const db = db.getSiblingDB('apigtac');

db.createUser({
    user: 'admin',
    pwd: 'abc456',
    roles: [
        { role: 'dbOwner', db: 'apigtac' }
    ]
});

db.createUser({
    user: 'powerbi',
    pwd: 'abc123',
    roles: [
        { role: 'read', db: 'apigtac' }
    ]
});
```

In this way, both roles are successfully created in 'apigtac' as the authentication database.

The problem is that this role does not place the limitations that I expected. For example, I have a collection called 'sitesurvey' inside 'apigtac' and if I use the user 'powerbi' which is supposed to have read role, I can remove the collection as follows:

```
use apigtac
db.sitesurvey.drop()
```

Is this behavior normal with the read role? How can I limit a user so that he cannot delete collections or databases?

EDIT. Here is a proof of what happens:

[TEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Aj0Y.png)

Comment: When you run your test, what is the output of `db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1})`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs This one:

{
  authInfo: {
    authenticatedUsers: [ { user: 'powerbi', db: 'apigtac' } ],
    authenticatedUserRoles: [ { role: 'read', db: 'apigtac' } ]
  },
  ok: 1
}

Comment: If you connect only as user `'powerbi'`, what are the results of your test?

Comment: Ocurrs the same. The result of executing 'db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1})' is identical and when I delete a collection, the result is only 'true'.

Comment: Curious.  What is the output of `db.runCommand({connectionStatus: 1, showPrivileges: true})`?

Comment: Do you have authentication enforced on the instance? If I recall correctly you can still successfully `.auth()` when connected to an instance even if auth/access control is not configured to be enforced by the process. What is the output of `db.adminCommand('getCmdLineOpts')`?